# How can i foreach this array result and echo in codeigniter view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> foreach this array result and echo the results

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [blog_title] => sooraj bloging
                [blog_id] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [blog_title] => What are Mobile App Testing Challenges?
                [blog_id] => 4
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [blog_title] => sooraj blog
                [blog_id] => 8
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => sooraj casestudy
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [career_id] => 14
                [title] => Software Engineer .NET sooraj
                [location] => Kochi, India.
                [description] => Developing .NET applications. 
                [qualification] => B.Tech. in CSE, MCA
                [status] => 0
                [created_at] => 2017-11-20 13:14:29
                [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tst_id] => 146
                [tst_name] => John Kasha
                [tst_quote] => Gadgeon was extremely professional and was easy to commun  sooraj icate and work with on a day-to-day basis. I also liked the fact that they were willing to do the research for specific tasks and present a viable solution or workaround to keep the project on schedule. I would recommend them for any task for any industry software or hardware. Bottom line, they get it done and you get results, not excuses. VP of Engineering.
                [tst_desig] => Vice President,Product Development and Engineering
                [tst_image] => 91c09ac9ee6234fdfcc523a393800bd5.jpg
                [url] => 
                [crop_name] => 668959f965ab28815dc97bbc1f8718d8.jpg
                [sysDate] => 2017-11-20 15:42:34
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: What results do you need? Everything ?

Comment: what you want to echo and your array data is non-symetrical. it's important to know what data you want from all this input array. everything? or part of it?

Comment: i  want both part by part and full  foreach and echo the all results @WillParky93@alive to Die

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: i know commonly use foreach of the single array but its nested array..and I am beginner to coding .plz help@Xatenev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Run this code

```
        <?php
    $array = array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'blog_title' => 'sooraj bloging',
                        'blog_id' => 2
                    ),
                    array(
                        'blog_title' => 'What are Mobile App Testing Challenges?',
                        'blog_id' => 4
                    ),
                    array(
                        'blog_title' => 'sooraj blog',
                        'blog_id' => 8
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'sooraj casestudy',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    array(
                        'career_id' => 14,
                        'title' => 'Software Engineer .NET sooraj',
                        'location' => 'Kochi, India.',
                        'description' => 'Developing .NET applications.',
                        'qualification' => 'B.Tech. in CSE, MCA',
                        'status' => 0,
                        'created_at' => '2017-11-20 13:14:29',
                        'updated_at' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                    )
                ),
                array(),
                array(
                    array(
                        'tst_id' => 146,
                        'tst_name' => 'John Kasha',
                        'tst_quote' => 'Gadgeon was extremely professional and was easy to commun  sooraj icate and work with on a day-to-day basis. I also liked the fact that they were willing to do the research for specific tasks and present a viable solution or workaround to keep the project on schedule. I would recommend them for any task for any industry software or hardware. Bottom line, they get it done and you get results, not excuses. VP of Engineering.',
                        'tst_desig' => 'Vice President,Product Development and Engineering',
                        'tst_image' => '91c09ac9ee6234fdfcc523a393800bd5.jpg',
                        'url' => '',
                        'crop_name' => '668959f965ab28815dc97bbc1f8718d8.jpg',
                        'sysDate' => '2017-11-20 15:42:34'
                    )
                )
            );

        foreach ($array as $value){
            foreach ($value as $row){
                foreach ($row as $key=> $row1){
                    echo $key.' - '. $row1;
                }
            echo '<br>';
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: actually i am using code for search keyword in different tables : I have many different table there are no common feilds to join ; so i give seprate search query and results of array return

Comment: Updated... Please try now,

Comment: thanks its working ..but sir i want to print the result of the array on one row .. next a nested array comes in next line...I am a beginner that's why plz help..

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you're trying to do (debugging vs tabular display), you can "pretty print" the array with [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) like so:

```
// Assuming your array is $data
echo '<pre>'.var_export($data, TRUE).'</pre>';
```

Otherwise, to loop through the array as is with a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
// Assuming your array is $data
foreach ($data as $subdata) {
    // You probably want to check that this is an array for case #3
    if(is_array($subdata)) {
         foreach ($subdata as $valueset) {
             // Check for array validity (not required for example data, but good to be safe)
             if (is_array($valueset)) {
                 foreach ($subdata as $key => $value) {
                     // Print each key, value pair as a row
                     echo $key .' => '.$value . '<br />';
                 }   
             }
         }
    } else {
        // Optional handling of empty set
        echo 'No data to display...';
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried but show error "Message: Array to string conversion" , controller $data['query'].

Comment: Ah, missed a layer, try it now

Comment: your code have a syntax error -->   if (is_array($valueset){

Comment: Ah, corrected that, one of the parenthesis lost its mate

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach  ($array as $value){
foreach  ($value as $row){
     if (is_array($row)){
            foreach  ($row as $key => $val){
                 echo $key."=>". $val."<br>";
             }///endForeach
         }///endIf
       else {
                echo $row;
      }////endElse
}
}
```